# Who should handle the team and receive status updates?

Tags: manager, conflict

I am an automation engineer with 10 years experience, recently promoted to Automation lead in my company.

My colleague who used to handle both automation and manual before, has responsibility to look after manual and the overall testing progress. But seeing my progress, he felt insecure and tried to get involved in the automation projects again. He was taking status updates and automation updates from people, which is what I am supposed to do.

In this process, I am confused, should I stop asking for updates and guiding people in day to day work or should I concentrate on my work only?

Comment: Only your boss can tell you what the responsibilities are supposed to be. Ask them.

Comment: Why do you care if someone else is collecting status from your team? If your boss has asked you to collect status from the team, then you do that. If someone else is *also* collecting status, that is their problem and none of your business.

Answer (score 1):

If you're the lead, then you are in the position to ask this other person to stand aside because part of a lead's duty is to facilitate a productive work environment for the team.  It's a loss of productivity for your team to need to give status to two separate people, and furthermore a loss of productivity for your boss to receive two team status reports for the same team that are never going to agree 100%.

You're on the right track.  You're not doing anything wrong.  Now it's time to ask the unwanted helper to fall back.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Company-culture you work in, you could also try to solve this directly. If, this is how I would approach this:

I would suggest to talk to your colleague. Thank him for his interest in the status updates. Tell him that you appreciate any advice he might have, as you are new to this position.

Ask him kindly not to bother your team directly. Tell that you don´t want to get you team confused about reporting lines and spare them the inefficiency of a double reporting. Instead offer to share your status updates with him. Talk about areas where you might have shared responsibilities and try to find each ones place in that areas. Maybe even meet regularly with him to discuss overall testing and team-leading issues.

Even if you are a little bit agitated about his meddling, try to see it as a chance to get some help and remind yourself that the other one is probably as confused as yourself about responsibilities. In the end it helps everyone to get to clearly defined roles and responsibilities and work together in a trusting and cooperative way.